# Can the mean value of a function be guaranteed to have some degree of regularity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. The mean value theorem tells us that for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $c=c(x,y) \in [0,1]$ such that:

\begin{equation}
f(y) -f(x) = \nabla f (x +c(x,y)(x-y) ) \cdot (y-x)
\end{equation}

I was wondering if by imposing enough regularity on $f$ (ex $f \in C^{1+\gamma} , C^2, C^{\infty}$) one could make $c(x,y)$ continuous, or even differentiable.

Comment: As it stands, $c(x,y)$ isn't even necessarily a function. I guess you could apply the implicit function theorem and arrive at sufficient conditions to have a $C^1$ *local* such function.